# Blender obj / fbx into Spline 3D / apply materials

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I have some blender models that render beautifully in blender (I'm a newbie to 3D), I can export them as obj or fbx files and import them into Spline, but the objects don't retain any of the material or texture information.

The colour of an object is retained, but not the material data and I don't appear to be able to import the mtl file either.

Does anyone know how to import or bake to an obj / fbx file the material information? Or do I have to manually recreate the materials in spline?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures